# The classic mystery "syntax error" VHDL-1261

Tags: debugging, vhdl, fpga

Please help I have tried everything I could think of (and found many unrelated errors in the process). I finally reduced it as much as possible and still the error survives.
Please save my sanity and increase my debugging checklist.

**Edit:**
**Thanks to the comments I figured out where the begin needed to be and all of the declares.**

> syntax error near if  VHDL1261 rock_pkg.vhd(33)

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;


package ROCK_PKG is
    type t_DATA_BUFFER is array (0 to 8) of unsigned (0 to 7);
    function TRIWAVE(input : t_DATA_BUFFER)
                return  t_DATA_BUFFER;
end ROCK_PKG;

package body ROCK_PKG is
    function TRIWAVE(input : t_DATA_BUFFER)
                    return  t_DATA_BUFFER is
    
       variable output : t_DATA_BUFFER;

       variable direction : std_logic := '0';
 
       if (direction)  --line 33
       then
       ...
       else
       ...
       end if;

       output = input + direction;

       return output;
    end TRIWAVE;
end ROCK_PKG;
```

Comment: Your `function` lacks a `begin` before the `if`. I also assume this is not the whole code as there is no `"+"` function defined for a `t_DATA_BUFFER` object and a `std_logic`;

Comment: Thank you! I have another section with the same error... ```variable singleCh : signed (0 to 16);
        singleCh(16) := signed(input(4)(0)); 
        singleCh(8 to 15) := signed(input(5)(0 to 7));  
        singleCh(0 to 7) := signed(input(6)(0 to 7));```

Comment: a variable can only be declared in the declarative region of the function. ie. before the `begin`

Comment: it is between output and direction. I had taken it out before

Comment: Commenting out the `...` character sequences (invalid syntax and a sequence of statements for the if statement is zero or more sequential statements) you'd find simulators generally have [friendlier syntax error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJoXm.jpg).

Comment: Christina, please [edit] your question if you have any new information. Down here in the comments it gets lost. -- Anf if you have another question, please post a new question.

Comment: I don't think, that it is possible to use a std_logic as boolean expression. I think you have to write `if (direction = '1')`.

Comment: @bananenkönig it is legal with vhdl2008

Comment: Oh thank you, haven't noticed that.